# page not redirecting in node

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to redirect to a different page from a function using HTML and Javascript. When I hardcode the URL it gets redirected, but when I put it in a variable it does not. please help.

I am using node version 8.x

```
  function p(){
     var c ="abc.com";
     var e = `
             <script type="text/javascript">
             function Redirect(){
             window.location=${c};
             }
             document.write("wait");
             setTimeout('Redirect()', 1000);
            </script>`
  return e;

  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change two things

1. add quotes around your passed page name
2. and remove quotes and parentheses from the timeout callback function

   ```
        ...
        window.location="${callback}";
        ...
        setTimeout(Redirect, 5000);
        ....
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You need to fix your setTimeout function:

```
 setTimeout(Redirect, 5000); // pass in a reference to the Redirect function and don't use quotes.
```

You can read more about setTimeout [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout).